# Making titles clickable

Tags: theme-development

http://thewowstudio.com/quad/

I want my titles to be clickable

Can anyone help me to figure it out how do I do this? I have been trying since a hour but no help.

thanks

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content
 *
 * Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
        <div class="featured-post">
            <?php _e( 'Featured post', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ! is_attachment() ) :
                the_post_thumbnail(array(400,200));
            endif; ?>

            <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
            <h3 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php else : ?>
            <h4 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h4>
            <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
            <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
                <div class="comments-link">
                    <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .comments-link -->
            <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
        <?php else : ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentytwelve' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <footer class="entry-meta">
            <?php twentytwelve_entry_meta(); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
            <?php if ( is_singular() && get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) && is_multi_author() ) : // If a user has filled out their description and this is a multi-author blog, show a bio on their entries. ?>
                <div class="author-info">
                    <div class="author-avatar">
                        <?php
                        /** This filter is documented in author.php */
                        $author_bio_avatar_size = apply_filters( 'twentytwelve_author_bio_avatar_size', 68 );
                        echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), $author_bio_avatar_size );
                        ?>
                    </div><!-- .author-avatar -->
                    <div class="author-description">
                        <h2><?php printf( __( 'About %s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?></h2>
                        <p><?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></p>
                        <div class="author-link">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
                                <?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- .author-link -->
                    </div><!-- .author-description -->
                </div><!-- .author-info -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </article><!-- #post -->
```

content.php

Comment: Which titles? What have you tried?

Comment: that is below to the main image over black background

Comment: UK start-up launches the first drone operations network - Business Review Europe

Comment: I have added content.php please check it. actually the main title that is below the  images over black background. I want them to be clickable. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However the answer of your problem havebeen given But in your site i have seen another  bug. In the right side bar of your site you have shown the product list but the title of the product is not showing click symbol on mouse hover like product image. If you want to solve that too than Problem is in following code shows below.

```
<div class="rightinerh1">
<a target="_blank" href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014HAGXGI"quadcoptersco-20"%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB014HAGXGI">
<label>JJRC H8D FPV Headless Mode 6-Axis 2.4Ghz Gyro RTF RC Quadcopter Helicopter Drone with 5.8G 2MP HD Camera Red EU Plug with US Adapter</label>
</a>
<label class="sidebarnewstime">$117.00</label>
<br>
</div>
```

As you can sea the above code contains all the formatting of your title.

```
Why is title is not showing click symbol?
```

Because In the above code `title text` are enclosed with in `<label>` tag. You need to remove that `<label>` tag so that your `<a>` tag can perform its functionality completely. Find out `<div class="rightinerh1">` and remove those labels. If you are using plugin than find out this div in your plugin folder otherwise find this div in your theme. In case of plugin before start searching that div you can try first plugin's admin section(in your dashboard) and sea all available settings that might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you need is to add a link to the respective article in your title.

The problem is not in your `index.php` but in your slider.
Find the .php file that contains this `div` :

```
<div class="amazingslider-title-1"> your title here </div>
```

and use the following code for the title inside the `div`

```
<div class="amazingslider-title-1">     
<?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: where do I add this?

Comment: I have added it but its not working still :(

Comment: Cant find this div. I have searched across my theme files using ctrl+F and checked whole theme but there is no such div

Comment: The slideshow is handled by the WonderPlugin.